# Call web services by alamofire respectively

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire

I'm creating an application that should call some web services in the begging of the app.
I've wrote a `WebServiceManager` that contains methods for calling web services and return result in `completionHandler`, here is one method of `WebServiceManager`:

```
extension WebServiceManager {
    func checkVersion(completionHandler: @escaping (CheckVersionResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        sessionManager?.adapter = BaseClientInterceptor()
        let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
        let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
        sessionManager?.request(Config.VERSION_URL + "/\(appVersion)/\(buildNumber)" + Config.STATUS, method: .get).responseData { response in
            print(response.response?.statusCode)
            switch response.result {

            case .success(let value):
                print("----WS: checkVersion Success-----")
                let value = JSON(value)
                print(value)
                let response = CheckVersionResponse(responseCode: response.response?.statusCode ?? -1)
                if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    response.setUrl(value["url"].string ?? "")
                    response.setNow(value["now"].intValue)
                    response.setStatus(value["status"].stringValue)
                    response.setMessage(value["message"].stringValue)
                }
                completionHandler(response, nil)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                print("----WS: checkVersion Failed-----")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I use some methods of this manager in `SplashScreenViewController`:

```
class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        WebServiceManager.shared.checkVersion() { response, error in
            //...
        }

        WebServiceManager.shared.getCurrentDate() { response, error in
            //...
        }

        WebServiceManager.shared.getUpdatedKeyValues() { response, error in
            //...
        }

        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasRegistered") {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToRegistration", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMain", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that this method runs line by line but it goes through to `if` at first.

How can I call these web services in order then make a decision based on `UserDefaults` values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sessionManager.request methods are asynchronous, so they will not execute synchronously (line by line) on viewDidAppear (by the way you are missing super.viewDidAppear())

If you want some code to execute after those 3 services you can do something like this, not sure if its the best solution tho:

```
class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    private var allDone = 0

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        WebServiceManager.shared.checkVersion() { response, error in
            //...
            checkUserDefault()
        }

        WebServiceManager.shared.getCurrentDate() { response, error in
            //...
            checkUserDefault()
        }

        WebServiceManager.shared.getUpdatedKeyValues() { response, error in
            //...
            checkUserDefault()
        }
    }

    private func checkUserDefault() {
        allDone += 1
        /// When all 3 services are finish
        if allDone == 3 {
            if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasRegistered") {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToRegistration", sender: self)
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToMain", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!

EDIT: This is the simplest solution based on your existing code, if you want to do it 'the right way' you may want to check Promises: http://khanlou.com/2016/08/promises-in-swift/ https://www.raywenderlich.com/9208-getting-started-with-promisekit

You need to use [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) and do something like this:

Replace your API methods so they use Promise as a response:

```
func checkVersion() -> Promise<CheckVersionResponse> {
        sessionManager?.adapter = BaseClientInterceptor()
        let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
        let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String

        // Return a Promise for the caller of this function to use.
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in

            // Inside the Promise, make an HTTP request
            sessionManager?.request(Config.VERSION_URL + "/\(appVersion)/\(buildNumber)" + Config.STATUS, method: .get).responseData { response in
                print(response.response?.statusCode)
                switch response.result {

                case .success(let value):
                    print("----WS: checkVersion Success-----")
                    let value = JSON(value)
                    print(value)
                    let response = CheckVersionResponse(responseCode: response.response?.statusCode ?? -1)
                    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        response.setUrl(value["url"].string ?? "")
                        response.setNow(value["now"].intValue)
                        response.setStatus(value["status"].stringValue)
                        response.setMessage(value["message"].stringValue)
                    }
                    fulfill(response)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    print("----WS: checkVersion Failed-----")
                    reject(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then on the UIViewController call the WebServiceManager methods like this:

```
WebServiceManager.shared.checkVersion().then { response in
    // ....
    WebServiceManager.shared.getCurrentDate()
    }.then { date in
        // ...
        WebServiceManager.shared.getUpdatedKeyValues()
    }.catch { error in
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your tricky solution, but I thought that somehow I can make it synchronize by `completionHandler`, and also I want the best solution and not sure about that yours is best or not

Comment: I've edited my answer in case it suits your needs better. Cheers!